# Svelte "has unused export property" warning?

Tags: svelte

There are times when I pass a component to another component, and it provides a standard set of properties when calling it (via `<svelte:component>`). But sometimes the called component doesn't need one or more of those properties. This gives me some unpleasant choices:

1. Omit the unneeded prop from the export list. This will result in
   Svelte warnings "`[component] was created with unknown prop..`."
2. Include the unneeded prop, just don't do anything with it. This will result in Svelte warnings "`[component] has unused export property...`"
3. Include the unneeded prop, but make an arbitrary reference to it to get the warning to go away. UGLY.
4. Include the unneeded prop, but set its default to undefined `unneededProp = undefined`. Still not very elegant. If I add a new prop to the standard list because some new component needs it, I have to add it to all the other components that don't need it just to keep them from throwing warnings.

What's the correct Svelty way to tell Svelte you are okay with unknown props in certain circumstances? I don't want to disable the warning application-wide, just when I'm using `<svelte:component this=... {standard set of properties that not every one needs}>`

Here's a simplified mock up of what I have:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import PanelSet from './PanelSet.svelte' // reusable generic panelling

  import Header from './PanelHeader.svelte' // app-specific
  import ViewSelector from './PanelViewSelector.svelte' // app-specific
  import ViewSet from './PanelViewSet.svelte'// app-specific

  let panels=[]

  let globalProps={
    // various props
  }
</script>

<PanelSet
    HeaderComponent = {Header}
    ViewSelectorComponent = {ViewSelector}
    ViewSetComponent = {ViewSet}
    {accessorDelegates}
    {globalProps}
    bind:panels
/>
```

```html
<!-- PanelSet.svelte -->
<script>
  // receive components as props
  export let HeaderComponent={}
  export let ViewSelectorComponent={}
  export let ViewSetComponent={}

  export let panels=[], accessorDelegates, globalProps
</script>
  <!-- within a CSS grid where the rows are panels and the columns panes -->
  <div id="frame" class="frame"
       style="grid-template-columns: {collapsiblePanelColumnWidths[0]}em {collapsiblePanelColumnWidths[1]}em {fixedColumnWidthCSS};
              grid-template-rows: repeat({panels.length},calc(100%/{panels.length}))">

    <!-- add one row per panel -->
    {#each panels as panel (panel.id) }
      <Panel
         {panel}
         {HeaderComponent}
         {ViewSelectorComponent}
         {ViewSetComponent}
         {accessorDelegates}
         {globalProps}
      />
    {/each}
  </div>

<style>
  .frame {
    height:100%;
    display:grid;
  }

</style>
```

```html
<!-- Panel.svelte -->
<script>
  export let panel
  export let HeaderComponent={}
  export let ViewSelectorComponent={} // PanelViewSelector component passed in here
  export let ViewSetComponent={}      // PanelViewSet component passed in here
  export let accessorDelegates, globalProps
</script>

<!-- Header component -->
<div class="header collapsible">
  <svelte:component this={HeaderComponent} {panel} {accessorDelegates} {globalProps} />
</div>

<!-- ViewSelector component -->
<div class="viewbuttonbox collapsible">
  <svelte:component this={ViewSelectorComponent} {panel} {accessorDelegates} {globalProps} />
</div>

<!-- ViewSet component -->
<div class="viewset">
  <svelte:component this={ViewSetComponent} {panel} {accessorDelegates} {globalProps} />
</div>
```

```html
<!-- PanelViewSelector.svelte -->
<script>
  export let panel, accessorDelegates // A warning is raised that the component is created with unknown prop 'globalProps'
  //  ... do stuff ... no need to touch globalProps
</script>
```

```html
<!-- PanelViewSet.svelte -->
<script>
  export let panel, accessorDelegates, globalProps
  //  ... do stuff ... including use of globalProps
</script>
```

NOTE: I'm using `<svelte:component>` because I cannot slot this from the top (`App.svelte`). Using slots would require that I call every component instance from `App.svelte`, but it is the `PanelSet` control that determines and creates multiple panels and therefore multiple instances of the requested components in each panel.

Unless there's a way for App.svelte to do an *array* of slots without having to incorporate virtually all of `PanelSet`'s and `Panel`'s logic in itself. `App.svelte` should be agnostic about the layout of the panelset and of each panel, whereas `PanelSet` and `Panel` should be agnostic about the application using it. They are meant to be a generic container I can use in other apps.

I know I can put all the props in a single object prop, but then every change to anything will reactive everything downstream, greatly increasing the cloud of reactions that flow from the top downward to all the various child components. I don't want an assignment to `globalOptions` to cause a reaction in `panels` or in `accessorDelegates`.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example with code? I don't really understand what you are doing.

Comment: Edited my question a code sample. Panel.svelte is meant to be a generic reusable container and hence does not know what child components it will have, nor what they need. So it must standardize the props it passes.

Comment: Those warnings only show in development mode and will not show in production, so just ignore them.

Comment: I will be in dev mode 100% of the time for the next year. If I ignore some, I will end up ignoring all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a design/approach issue. One generally should not need to pass components around that often, in most cases slots are more flexible. Given this example:

```html
<div class="header collapsible">
  <slot name="header" />
</div>
<div class="viewbuttonbox collapsible">
    <slot name="view-selector" />
</div>
<div class="viewset">
    <slot name="view-set" />
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<Panel>
  <PanelViewSelector slot="view-selector" {panel} {accessorDelegates} />
  <!-- ... -->
</Panel>
```

In the example `panel` and the other passed properties came from the outside so the above would work in such a scenario. If any values should be passed from the `Panel` component itself, that can be done via slot properties.

```html
<div class="header collapsible">
  <slot name="header" propFromPanel={42} />
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<Panel>
  <svelte:fragment slot="view-selector" let:propFromPanel>
    <PanelViewSelector {panel} ... something={propFromPanel} />
  </svelte:fragment>
  <!-- ... -->
</Panel>
```

(As you seem to be passing things along multiple levels, you might also want to consider using [contexts](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) rather than properties.)

Another approach would be to bundle those properties into an object and pass that as a single property, so you would have `export let panelProps` which contains `panel`, `accessorDelegates` and `globalProps`.

The property could be reactively destructured to make using it easier:

```html
<script>
    export let panelProps;
    $: ({ panel, accessorDelegates } = panelProps) // Parentheses required
</script>
```

Comment: I wrote this piece of my app early on, before knowing about slots. I've used the slot approach elsewhere after learning of it. Now I wonder if I should retrofit this old code in after the same manner. Question: if slots are so much more flexible than using <svelte:component>, when is it advantageous to use this latter method? Are slots always preferred?

Comment: You need `svelte:component` when the component does not come from the outside and you don't know exactly what type of component it is or the component has to be switched dynamically (the value of `this={...}` can change). So generally there is little reason to use it, though it can be more concise if the component does not need additional input, e.g. if you have SVGs turned into components and you just want to pass those to a button: `<Button icon={Folder} />`.

Comment: I just realized why I can't use slots for this. I edited my question with more code and explanation. The problem is that parent PanelSet creates multiple panels (Panel) and every one of them need the components that the top-level App component requests.

Comment: There isn't anything preventing slots from being passed into other slots, so this does not require the direct passing of components. But you might want to think about simplifying this altogether, passing things down multiple levels is not ideal to begin with.

Comment: The PanelSet+Panel pair of components needs to instantiate the components passed to them multiple times (they control how many panels they create, and the same set of components need to be on each panel).  How can slots do that?

Comment: Why would passing things down multiple levels not be good? Having direct lines of property communication from top to bottom seems like it provides better isolation and control over reaction order than global methods such as stores. Stores feels analogous to writing procedural code with all global variables instead of architecting proper routine-to-routine communication. Easy to do but makes a mess.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Regarding multiples: You can instantiate a slot any number of times, If a slot appears in an `each` you get multiple instances of it. It would not even be instantiated there anyway, as the slot would be passed down into a slot of `Panel`, and panel is what gets multiple instances through `#each` here.

Comment: I am not advocating for throwing globals at the problem, as noted in my answer, you could use contexts, which are scoped to component subtrees. If you have to pass everything manually through every level you create overhead, the code becomes harder to read because of all the mess and you increase error surface area. Contexts have their own drawbacks, but I would prefer it over this.